# Can this concept be optimized with OpenMP?

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, openmp

I'd rather not use code since it's common concept:

Say we have the scenario of a function which is neither too big or too small and also can't easily in itself be optimized with OpenMP for-loop optimizations.

However, it is a function which is called millions of times throughout the project's run in a few hundred unrelated circumstances in the code.

[inline in itself doesn't seem to do much (on by default on optimized gcc outcomes) and making it into a macro while not parallel either, it would be an undertaking to be compatible.]

Comment: This is too general. The answer completely depends on your function, and how that function is actually called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the function is called, is it called multiple times, particularly in a loop?  The question is a little vague -- maybe yes (it's called thousands of times in each of a few hundred unrelated places -> millions) or maybe no (it's called once in each of a hundred unrelated places, and you hit those sections of code thousands of times -> millions).

In the first case, then yes, parallelizing the `map' -- that is, applying the function independantly to a bunch of cases -- is easy and OpenMPs very well.

In the second case, if the function is called a million times but each time once, then no.   There's *repetition* of execution there, but no exposed *concurrency*; there's no list of tasks that have to be done at the same time that can be done independantly.    All that you can do there, if the function is likely to be called with repeated parameters, is to use memoization, which is a memory/compute time tradeoff, not a parallelization technique.

In the second case, it may be the case that you can restructure the code so that a bunch of those function calls are made at once, thus exposing the concurrency and allowing parallelization -- but its not something that OpenMP (or any parallel programming model) can automatically do for you.

Answer (score 2):

OpenMP is for *"making things run in parallel"* - in general. Not only `for` loops... Well, you don't even need to have any loops at all to make some good use of OpenMP and speed up your code.

The only thing which matters is: *"do I have a several **independent** operations which run one after one, and which could work at the same time instead?"*. If so, then you've found an easy spot for optimization with OpenMP.